# Simple Inequality Question

Tags: real-analysis

Given $a>b>0$

How can I prove that $\frac{1}{b} >\frac{1}{a}$ or in other words $b^{-1}>a^{-1}$

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a>b>0$ or, $a-b>0$, dividing by $ab>0$, you will get:

$$\frac{a-b}{ab}=\frac{1}{b}-\frac{1}{a}>0$$

Answer (score 4):

You can start from $a-b \gt 0$, divide by $ab$, and ...

Comment: Or just divide the original given by $ab$ ...